# Query result into desired format (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello everyone i have some question about query on MySQL database.

I have table name TEST like this

```
DATE        PRODUCT
2008-01-01  10
2008-01-01  20
2008-02-01  30
2008-02-01  40
```

And i want a query that can select like this

```
DATE        PRODUCT
2008-01-01  15
2008-02-01  35
```

Where PRODUCT is came from AVERAGE value from their DATE.
Thanks

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `AVG()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

`select date, AVG(PRODUCT) from TEST GROUP BY date`

Answer (score 0):

You could group the results by the date and apply the [`avg`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) aggregate function:

```
SELECT   `date`, AVG(`product`) AS 'Product'
FROM     `test`
GROUP BY `date`
```